# Ansible playbook not working trying to run make & configure with complex switches

Tags: vagrant, ansible

This is a follow-on to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/573505/ansible-playbook-not-working-trying-to-run-patch) question. I'm trying to use Ansible to provision a Vagrant VM. The VM is running CentOS 6.4. I'm using the following (abbreviated) ansible playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: default
  vars:
    home: '/home/vagrant'
    curl_version: '7_19_7'
    curl_url: 'https://github.com/bagder/curl/archive/curl-{{ curl_version }}.tar.gz'
    curl_dir: '{{ home }}/curl-curl-{{ curl_version }}'

  # user: vagrant
  remote_user: vagrant
  sudo: yes

  tasks:

  - name: Ensure required packages and installed and up to date - pt1
    yum: pkg={{ item }} state=present
    with_items:
      - make
      - gcc
      - etc...

  # Lots more yum tasks in here

  - name: Ensure CURL source downloaded
    get_url: url={{ curl_url }} dest=/home/vagrant/curl-{{ curl_version }}.tar

  - name: Extract CURL source
    command: tar -zxf {{ home }}/curl-{{ curl_version }}.tar creates={{ curl_dir }}

  - name: Copy ssh patch over
    copy: src=./files/ssh.c.patch dest={{ home }}/ssh.c.patch

  - name: Patch CURL with openssl
    shell: patch -t {{ curl_dir }}/lib/ssh.c {{ home }}/ssh.c.patch chdir={{ curl_dir }}/lib
    when: path_file_result.changed

  - name: Build CURL with openssl
    command: 'chdir={{ curl_dir }} "{{ item }}"'
    with_items:
      - ./buildconf
      - ./configure --with-gssapi --with-libidn --with-libssh2 --prefix=/usr --without-nss
      - make
      - make install
      - ldconfig
```

Vagrant is working fine and the Ansible playbook runs successfully up to the last task 'Build CURL with openssl' - which fails, like so:

```
    TASK: [Build CURL with openssl] *********************************************** 
    changed: [default] => (item=./buildconf) => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["./buildconf"], "delta": "0:00:10.709817", "end": "2014-02-07 02:26:44.802652", "item": "./buildconf", "rc": 0, "start": "2014-02-07 02:26:34.092835", "stderr": "configure.ac:78: installing `./compile'
    configure.ac:73: installing `./config.guess'
    configure.ac:73: installing `./config.sub'
    configure.ac:65: installing `./missing'
    Makefile.am: installing `./depcomp'
    configure.ac:137: installing `./config.guess'
    configure.ac:137: installing `./config.sub'
    docs/examples/Makefile.am: installing `./depcomp'", "stdout": "buildconf: autoconf version 2.63 (ok)
    buildconf: autom4te version 2.63 (ok)
    buildconf: autoheader version 2.63 (ok)
    buildconf: automake version 1.11.1 (ok)
    buildconf: aclocal version 1.11.1 (ok)
    buildconf: libtool version 2.2.6 (ok)
    buildconf: libtoolize found
    buildconf: GNU m4 version 1.4.13 (ok)
    buildconf: running libtoolize
    buildconf: running aclocal
    buildconf: running aclocal hack to convert all mv to mv -f
    buildconf: running autoheader
    buildconf: cp lib/curl_config.h.in src/curl_config.h.in
    buildconf: running autoconf
    buildconf: running in ares
    buildconf: running automake
    buildconf: OK"}

    failed: [default] => (item=./configure --with-gssapi --with-libidn --with-libssh2 --prefix=/usr --without-nss) => {"cmd": ["./configure --with-gssapi --with-libidn --with-libssh2 --prefix=/usr --without-nss"], "failed": true, "item": "./configure --with-gssapi --with-libidn --with-libssh2 --prefix=/usr --without-nss", "rc": 2}
    msg: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
    failed: [default] => (item=make) => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["make"], "delta": "0:00:00.001828", "end": "2014-02-07 02:26:45.003968", "item": "make", "rc": 2, "start": "2014-02-07 02:26:45.002140"}
    stderr: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
    failed: [default] => (item=make install) => {"cmd": ["make install"], "failed": true, "item": "make install", "rc": 2}
    msg: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
    changed: [default] => (item=ldconfig) => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["ldconfig"], "delta": "0:00:00.009685", "end": "2014-02-07 02:26:46.096829", "item": "ldconfig", "rc": 0, "start": "2014-02-07 02:26:46.087144", "stderr": "", "stdout": ""}

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

So, the `./buildconf` step works, but the `./configure --with-gssapi --with-libidn --with-libssh2 --prefix=/usr --without-nss` step seems to be failing with `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`. I presume this is because it's trying to run that whole string like it was a single command?

If I change it to use `shell` instead of `command`, I get this instead:

```
failed: [default] => (item=./configure --with-gssapi --with-libidn --with-libssh2 --prefix=/usr --without-nss) => {"changed": true, "cmd": " \"./configure --with-gssapi --with-libidn --with-libssh2 --prefix=/usr --without-nss\" ", "delta": "0:00:00.001171", "end": "2014-02-07 02:31:34.862373", "item": "./configure --with-gssapi --with-libidn --with-libssh2 --prefix=/usr --without-nss", "rc": 127, "start": "2014-02-07 02:31:34.861202"}
stderr: /bin/sh: ./configure --with-gssapi --with-libidn --with-libssh2 --prefix=/usr --without-nss: No such file or directory
```

I've verified that all the tasks up to that point work, and the files are downloaded and extracted to the expected places and the patch works ([see here](https://serverfault.com/questions/573505/ansible-playbook-not-working-trying-to-run-patch)).

After the task fails (or if you comment it out), if you SSH into the VM that's being configured, and run all the same build steps yourself - using the exact values from the playbook, it works.

I'm still pretty new to Ansible and I'm not sure why this isn't working? What am I doing wrong? Is there some way to format or quote that `configure` command differently so it gets interpreted properly, if that's the issue? Should I be using `raw` for this? Or something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solution is to change this:

```yaml
shell: 'chdir={{ curl_dir }} "{{ item }}"'
```

to this:

```yaml
shell: "{{ item }}"
args:
  chdir: "{{ curl_dir }}"
```

The [documentation for the shell module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html) now addresses this trickiness in the formatting.
The complete working build task currently looks like this:

```yaml
- name: Build CURL with openssl
  shell: "{{ item }}"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ curl_dir }}"
  with_items:
    - ./buildconf
    - ./configure --with-gssapi --with-libidn --with-libssh2 --prefix=/usr --without-nss
    - make
    - make install
    - ldconfig
```