# Why does an `"[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc"` issue occur when Ansible is executed remotely?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Running:

```
- name: get vhosts
  command: rabbitmqctl list_vhosts
  register: vhosts
  changed_when: false
```

by issuing

```
sudo ansible-playbook file.yml
```

results in:

```
TASK [030.sensu : get vhosts] **************************************************
fatal: [IP]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "rabbitmqctl list_vhosts", 
"failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

while this error does not occur if ansible is run on the system itself.

---

**Discussion**

*1. Is the `rc` command missing?*

Issuing `rc` both locally as remotely results in:

```
bash: rc: command not found...
```

If this would be an issue then running the playbook locally would fail as well.

---

*2. Is this a known issue?*

Querying `"No such file or directory" rc ansible centos` on the internet resulted in [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/573505/215599).

According to [one of the answers](https://serverfault.com/a/573510/215599) the issue is caused by `command`. Using `shell` instead would solve the problem. The solution was tried, but it did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The return from ansible is json. Pretty printed:

```
{
  "changed": false,
  "cmd": "rabbitmqctl list_vhosts",
  "failed": true,
  "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory",
  "rc": 2
}
```

You'll note `msg` contains "[Errno 2] No such file or directory". Instead `rc` is the return (exit) code, '2' in your case, of the command `rabbitmqctl list_vhosts`.

In shell (bash/sh/whatever) run `rabbitmqctl`. You may not have `rabbitmqctl` installed. Or, as EEAA rightfully suggests, it is not in `$PATH`. On some distros (Debian/Ubuntu) `/usr/sbin` is not included in normal users' path, but it is included for root.

Comment: ...or it's not in the `PATH`.

Comment: @EEAA Confirmed: [Symlinking `/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin` to `/usr/lib/rabbitmq/sbin`](https://github.com/Stouts/Stouts.rabbitmq/blob/develop/tasks/rabbitmq.yml#L31) solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `become: true` to the file.yml:

```
- hosts:
    - <enter-IP>
  roles:
    - 030.sensu
  become: true
```

and running it by issuing `ansible-playbook file.yml` solved the issue as well.